# ANDROID adding a new package

Tags: android, layout, package

In my project I have got some classes and some layouts. I add a new package to my project and I in new classes from this new package there is a problem: e.g. when I writing "setContentView(R.layout.author_xml);" I have got red underline and comunicate: "R cannot be resolved to a variable". In adnroid manifest when I use activity from new package I add:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tom"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<activity
    android:name=".menu.NewGameActivity"><!--I add .menu-->
</activity>
```

Generally in classes from new package I can't see a layout. Maybe I should add something in layout, e.g:
android:package="com.tom.menu" -> but it doesn't work.
What can I do in this situation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe do a clean and rebuild, and just to be sure restart eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a class in a subpackage, e.g. `com.tom.mypackage`, you have to import your `R` from base package mentioned in manifest. Just put import statement into you classes which are in subpackages and which don't see the `R`:

```
package com.tom.menu; // class in subpackage

import com.tom.R;  // This will get you your R from base package

import android.app.Activity;

public class NewGameActivity extends Activity {

// use R here like you are used to

// remainder omitted...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `R` class in your code file. The class is generated in the package that is in your app manifest I believe. If you're using eclipse, you should see the generated `R` class in the project explorer and you can see what package it's in. There is also an `android.R` package which contains all assets that are bundled with the android OS. It has some cool stuff in it, but it is unrelated to your problem.